# Android - Button in Dialog out of screen

Tags: android, listview, dialog, android-alertdialog

I created an `AlertDialog` which is longer than the actual screen size. Within my `AlertDialog` I have a `ListView` which I can scroll down to see all items.

My problem is with my `Button`: it is half displayed in the bottom of the screen.

Here is what it looks like :

[image: Button out of bound]

It seems that the button is not considered to be within the `View`.
What should I do to keep the everything inbound?

Thank you. Leo

---

**EDIT**

As you said I might do something weird, I took a closer look at my code before posting you it.

I found that I didn't remove the `builder.setMessage()` that I used at the beginning. So after removing that line, it worked fine. Now the entire `ListView` is displayed!

Comment: Are you doing anything weird in the code?  Can you post it?

Comment: If you're inflating a layout to use as the Dialog view, post the XML as well. If not, the code you're using to create the view for the dialog should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said I might do something weird, I took a closer look at my code before posting you it.

I found that I didn't remove the builder.setMessage() that I used at the beginning. So after removing that line, it worked fine. Now the entire ListView is displayed!

Answer (score 0):

Put a set height for your `ListView` so that the dialog isn't as tall. `80dp` or so should be enough to show your button and enough of the `ListView`